Not able to locate the element from date picker expedia.com
Could anyone guide me how to select date range from date picker on expedia.com in selenium python?
for example: Go to expedia/flights
click on Dates and select current day to next 7 days.
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

ac = ActionChains(driver)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/Flights")

dates_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="FlightSearchForm_ROUND_TRIP"\]/div/div\[2\]')
ac.click(dates_btn).perform()

calendar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="FlightSearchForm_ROUND_TRIP"\]/div/div\[2\]/div/section')
ac.move_to_element(calendar).perform()

I tried to test to select the month and year on the top of right calendar but encounter the error unable to locate the element
right_month_year = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="FlightSearchForm_ROUND_TRIP"\]/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div\[1\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/h2')
print(month_year.text)


Here is the working code with explanation for each line in the code:
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/Flights")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on date picker button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "date_form_field-btn"))).click()

# By default calendar opens up next month(Nov). Below line will click on back button to go to Oct month
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[@data-stid='date-picker-paging'])[1]"))).click()

# Click on Oct 23rd. Change the XPath if you want to select some other day
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label,'Oct 23, 2024')]"))).click()

# Click on Oct 30th. Change the XPath if you want to select some other day
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label,'Oct 30, 2024')]"))).click()

# Click on 'Done' button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-stid='apply-date-picker']"))).click()
time.sleep(20)

Result:


Thank Shawn. It works great. I appreciate for active help and answer.

Glad it helped resolve the issue. What should I do when someone answers my question?
